# Pycharm message "Process error=5, Access is denied" from run flake8

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, flake8

I'm trying to use flake8 in PyCharm for Python 3. I got this error code when I try to run flake8:

```
"Error running Flake8: Cannot run program "D:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\flake8\plugins" (in directory "D:\Python_my\Python_netology_homework"): CreateProcess error=5, , Access is denied"
```

I installed flake8 in **File -> Settings -> External Tools** however PyCharm says flake 8 is installed in **D:\Python36\Lib\site-packages\flake8**. and uses this path in flake8 settings.

For a visual, see [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tl5x4n4aemrqr9q/%D0%A1%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%88%D0%BE%D1%82%202017-07-10%2016.28.02.png?dl=0)

Answer (score 0):

You say you `installed flake8 in File | Settings | External tools`, However, nothing gets installed through that menu. It is called `External tools` because these are tools which are installed outside of PyCharm, and you are running these external tools through PyCharm.

If you are wanting to run `External Tools` in `PyCharm`, here is how I typically do it and my recommendation:

1. Install [flake8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8) on your computer.
2. Get a command line version of the tool to work (including if you are on windows)
3. **Then** try to get the `External Tools` to work in `PyCharm`. Your `Program` will be the first argument that you gave on the command line. `Parameters` will be everything else. `Working directory` will be where you kick it off. Also, the `Insert macro...` button is really helpful when setting these up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add python interpreter in project settings, navigate to :
*File | Settings | Project: pythonProject | Python Interpreter*
Click on Python Interpreter dropdown and Show all. After set yor path to python.exe file.
Example: C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe